# Is an SLA pulled by just the calls answered by a certain group and not for the whole Queue valid?

Tags: estimation, validation

I am trying to determine if the following is a valid SLA, I was presented with this as a fix for us not being able to differentiate the SLA between multiple groups answering calls:

- 1 Queue
- Two Groups handling that queue (`Group A` & `Group B`)
- SLA is met for a call when it is answered within 40 seconds (40s wait time)

Queue had 100 calls for the day, with an average SLA of 70%. `Group A` answered 40 calls, `Group B` answered 60 calls from the same queue.

To determine the SLA for the groups individually, the method that was presented was to look at the wait time only for the calls answered by that group. So the SLA for `Group A` would be determined by looking at the wait time for the 40 calls they answered, and for `Group B` for the 60 calls they answered.

To me this seems skewed, as you are only looking at what was answered, for all intents and purposes wouldn't this be like picking random calls from those 100 for the day and calculating a service level? Expand this out to 1,000,000 calls and I would assume `Group A` and `Group B` should have a similar service level as the Queue average (All other factors being equal)?

Is this flawed, if not, why is it accurate? If so, why is it flawed?

Note: I am not sure what to tag this, please edit this as needed.

Comment: I agree that the proposed idea has issues. Just to clarify: calls are not assigned to a group from the queue, they are grabbed by the next person to pick up, who might be from Group A or Group B, correct?

Comment: The calls ring for everyone at once, it's not a round-robin based on available time. Not sure if that has an affect. The calls are not assigned to groups in this case. They are all getting calls from the same bucket of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your point is partially correct.

In your example, if Group A and Group B both generally have the same number of people sitting and waiting for a call, it looks like Group B is quicker to pick up on a call. In reality, this might save the customer a ring or two, and probably has zero effect on SLA. (In fact, if Group B is tensely hovering over the phone waiting to catch it on the first half-ring, they may not actually give your customers the best service experience.)

On the other hand, during times that everyone's pretty much busy talking to customers, the person who happens to get off of one call and pick up another that's been ringing too long (non-SLA) is pretty much random. So attributing this non-SLA call to a particular team doesn't make a lot of sense.

Even worse, if Group B is twice as large as Group A, they will take twice as many non-SLA calls during crunch times and look bad, simply because they have more exposure to long-ringing calls.

I think the more important question, though, is what are you trying to incentivize here?

Using the proposed counting method, the first group that learns to never answer a call that's rung for 40 seconds (allowing the other group to answer the call and take an SLA hit) will win in SLA stats. The second group that learns this will take your customer service down with it.

Comment: Thanks Wayne! The reason I ask is because another team decided that this is how they where going to display our SLA. After learning how it was being determined, I felt that the results are not very meaningful, but was unable to really pin point why.